# Inject a TypeListener

Tags: java, guice

I have this scenario where I want to inject a `TypeListener` with dependencies, but it will never work because the `TypeListener` is used to actually perform the injection.

How can I get this thing done? Is there a *guicey*-way?

Notes:

- I'm using Guice 4.0
- `MyManager` will be used after `Guice::createInjector`.
- Both `MyManager::registerType` and `MyManager::use` are called exclusively before `Guice::createInjector` returns.
- `MyDependency` is present to show that `MyManager` cannot be instanciated with `new`. I will also be used after `Guice::createInjector` has returned.

I created the following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to showcase my issue:

```
import com.google.inject.*;
import com.google.inject.matcher.*;
import com.google.inject.spi.*;

public class MyClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
  }

  static class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override protected void configure() {
      TypeListener listener = new MyTypeListener();
      requestInjection(listener);
      bindListener(Matchers.any(), listener);
    }
  }

  static class MyTypeListener implements TypeListener {
    @Inject MyManager manager;
    @Override public <I> void hear(TypeLiteral<I> type, TypeEncounter<I> encounter) {
      Class<?> rawType = type.getRawType();
      manager.registerType(rawType);
      encounter.register(new InjectionListener<I>() {
        @Override public void afterInjection(I injectee) {
          manager.use(rawType, injectee);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @Singleton static class MyManager {
    @Inject MyManager(MyDependency dependency) { }
    void registerType(Class<?> type) {  }
    void use(Class<?> type, Object injectee) { }
  }

  static class MyDependency { }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at least some of the time (in tests or code analysis) type listeners have no cohesion to the types they are listening to, so there's no reason to have one injector. You'd use one injector to create the listener and one injector to create the code to be tested/analyzed.

If you really want one injector (e.g. if the types in the injector you wish to listen to and the types needed by the listener are cohesive) then your best bet is AbstractModule's getProvider() method. So, if MyTypeListener needs an instance of Foo, this is what MyModule would look like:

```
   static class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
     @Override protected void configure() {
       TypeListener listener = new MyTypeListener(getProvider(Foo.class));
       bindListener(Matchers.any(), listener);
     }
   }
```

If you haven't used `getProvider()`, be forewarned that you cannot call `.get()` on the provider until the injector is constructed. As long as you don't call it from the context of the listener's constructor you should be fine.

Comment: This is the same solution as the one I wrote and which fails: using a provider or making a direct injection here has exactly the same impact.

Comment: That's odd, I see multiple instances of this pattern in production code. If you could delay calling .get() until after injection it would probably work.

Comment: I mean in the body of afterInjection() rather than in the scope of hear(). I don't know if it fits your use case, but if you put the type in a final variable and only register it with the manager at that point, it ought to work based on the code I'm looking at.

Comment: Okay, it works. To be concrete, I use `AbstractModule::getProvider` as you mention and I call `MyManager::registerType` in `MyManager::use` if needed and this does it. The exception handling in my real-life scenario is a bit clunky but that's ok.